# Calling REST API in android during development

Tags: android, rest, localhost

I have implemented a REST API using Node, Express and MongoDB, and made a webapp using the same. Now I want to create an android application which consumes this API, but I don't wish to spend money on a server while in development. Is there a way to use this API in android without uploading it to a server?

PS: I do not wish to create the app using Cordova/PhoneGap. I want to build a native android app in Java.

Comment: then use parse.com free backend for your webservice but with some limits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deploy your API to a service like heroku.

Its free and good.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-app-to-heroku

Comment: I'll do this. But is there any other alternative, ie, without uploading it to a server, but creating kind of a local server using my PC which the app can access?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/586914/node-js-forwarding-from-local-network-to-public-internet